# Webm video format disappears in mobile both in android and iPhone in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, video, webp, webm

Hi I'm using alpha videos in Webm format, everything is working well in desktop, however when it come to iPad or mobile the video is not appearing, this is happening in all browser

below is my code

`<video muted autoPlay loop > <source src='/assets/v2.webm' type='video/webm' /> </video>`

Comment: **(1)** For a faster answer you need to provide something testable. Can the problem be reproduced just using HTML (no Next.js code) and one WebM video file with Alpha channel? Could you make such a [simple demo page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video) on your site? **(2)** Are you using CSS options like Z-index anywhere in the un-shown part of your code? **(3)** You say it disappears, but can you still hear sound from such transparent video? Knowing these details might help others to give useful answers.